# how to compare two javascript array using angular.foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two javascript Object

```
    var obj1= {
           key1:'value1',
           key2:'value2'
    };
```

And

```
 var obj2= {
           key1:'value1',
           key2:'someOtherValue'
    };
```

As you can see there is one difference b/w both objects at `key2`, i want a angular foreach loop which can check both objects and can return a console message "Difference is at key2". I already tried angular foreach but it doesn't allow more than one object so how should i compare?

Comment: do you like to compare the value of the same key? why angular?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133885/angularjs-compare-two-arrays

Comment: i am already working on angular js, obj1 is coming from database and obj2 is user input i want to check difference field by field

Comment: It's not duplicate this answer is for array i want to compare objects.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use angular.foreach.

- Javascript `for` is faster.
- you wont be able to use break in angular.foreach.

---

```
var diffs = [];
for (var key in obj1) {
   if obj1[key] !== obj2[key]{
     diffs.append([key]);
   }
}
console.log(diffs)
```

Assuming both dictionaries have same keys..

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for it.

```js
var obj1 = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' },
    obj2 = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'someOtherValue' },
    map = new Map();

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => map.set(k, obj1[k]));
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(k => map.get(k) !== obj2[k] && console.log(k + ' is different'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure angularjs code with angular foreach loop.

```
var keepGoing = true;
angular.forEach(obj1, function(value, key){
    angular.forEach(obj2, function(value2, key2){
        if(keepGoing) {
            if(value == value2){
                keepGoing = true;
            }
            else{
                console.log('Difference is at', key2)
                keepGoing = false;
            }
        }
    })
})
```