# Facing problem while comparing two javaScript array along with values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

```js
var obj1 = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: [] },
    obj2 = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'someOtherValue', key3: [] },
    map = new Map();

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => map.set(k, obj1[k]));
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(k => map.get(k) !== obj2[k] && console.log(k + ' is different'));
```

I taken the piece of code from
[how to compare two javascript array using angular.foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384929/how-to-compare-two-javascript-array-using-angular-foreach)
but in my scenario need to add array also in map, So please help me out from this.
Thanks.

Comment: so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: In both object key3 values is same('[]') but in console its getting different.

Comment: its not the same, they may both have no elements but they are not the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, but how can i check there is no element difference in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stringify the value to get a comparable value.

The original code checks the value with primitive types. By using objects, the object reference is used for checking. If you have two different arrays, you have two different object references.

```js
var obj1 = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: [] },
    obj2 = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'someOtherValue', key3: [] },
    map = new Map();

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => map.set(k, obj1[k]));
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(k => {
    const value = map.get(k);
    if (value !== obj2[k] && JSON.stringify(value) !== JSON.stringify(obj2[k])) {
        console.log(k + ' is different');
    }
});
```

Comment: only works if the values of the arrays are supported, ex `undefined`, `function(){}`, `Symbol('')` and `null` will all be transformed into nulls during `JSON.stringify`, sets and maps will also be transformed into objects