# My if statement doesnt look to be satisfied inside foreach in angularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Im fairly new to JS. However, the if statment inside the foreach never seems to satisfy. Im guessing its the call back nature of foreach on array thats not happy ?

Example Array used:

```
Array 1: 
[{
  Value: 43
}]

Array 2:
[{
  Items : 
  {
    Value: 43,
     Name: Car
  },
  {
    Value: 44,
    Name: MotorBike
  }
}]
```

What ive tried so far:

```
    array1.forEach(function (list1)

    {
        array2.Items.forEach(function (Item)
        {
            if (list1.Value == Item.Value)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**
Can see the foreach was working well on this thread
[angularjs compare two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133885/angularjs-compare-two-arrays)

Unsure why it didnt work for me.
The below code works, yet, im curious on what didnt on the first approach:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++)
    {
       if (array[i].Value=== array2[j].Value)
       {
          return true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share examples of the `array1` and `array2` values you have?

Comment: hi @Mureinik : i have updated my question, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is the strict comparison with `===` as described here: https://codeahoy.com/javascript/2019/10/12/==-vs-===-in-javascript/

In this case it is likely that your previous comparison returned a *false negative* because the type of the item and indeed the `.Value` was not strictly determinable at runtime.

Without the full code and working example that shows how the arrays are instantiated we can only speculate, but this is a common solution to comparison logic, use strict equals in all cases for primitive value comparisons unless you really do mean to interpolate the values.